# Is it inefficient that every mounted graphQL component just requeries all the time?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, graphql-js

So, I'm using Apollo-link-state for local state management on an app I'm building, and I have a Modal component that pops up if `modalData` in the state changes. For it to listen to this, it's wrapped in a `<Query>` component, like so:

```
render(){
    return (
        <Query query={GET_MODAL_DATA}>
          {({data}) => {
            const currentModal = data.currentModal;

            return (
                <CSSTransition in={currentModal.operation ? true : false} unmountOnExit classNames="modal" timeout={{ enter: 1, exit: 200 }}>
                    <div className="modal-container" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                        <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                            <h2>
                                { currentModal.operation+' '+currentModal.dataType }
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </CSSTransition>
            )
          }}
        </Query>
    )
}
```

with this arrangement, however, it re-renders (and re-queries) no matter what you do.

Change route? Re-renders. Change another component's local state? Re-renders. Change text fields? Re-renders.

Perhaps this is how Apollo is meant to work, but coming from Redux it seems kinda inefficient for every mounted component to re-query if you so much as breathe in the direction of your browser.

Is that what it's meant to do, or have I set something up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

react-apollo will re-query every time unless you set the [fetchPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#query-props) to `network-only`.

As for the re-renders, it is more of a React issue than it is apollo.

You see, every time a state or a prop changes, react will run the component `render()` function. If react finds that the props for a component changed, it will re-render the component.

Since you are using an inline function as the children prop for `Query` component, this will cause re-rendering every time because every instance of a function is a reference to a different memory address, and thus is perceived as different. What you could do about this is to take out the function into: let's say, `this.renderModal`. Then, just pass the function a children to `Query` like this:

```
<Query>{this.renderModal}</Query>
```

This will ensures that the children prop passed to `Query` is the same function every time.

Second, you are passing a literal object `{ enter: 1, exit: 200 }` to `CSSTransition` component. This has the same issue as above. Every instance of an object also has reference to different memory address, even if the value is exactly the same. One thing you can do about this is to take out the object, put it into `constructor` like

`this.transitionTimeout = { enter: 1, exit: 200 };`

and then pass that variable as a prop like:

`<CSSTransition timeout={this.transitionTimeout}`

This will ensures that the prop will point to the same object every time, thus preventing re-render.

Update:
You might also want to checkout about `React.PureComponent`. Here is an [article](http://lucybain.com/blog/2018/react-js-pure-component/) that explains about it pretty well. Basically react will compare the value of the previous and next props shallowly, and if it is equal, it will not trigger `render`.